# Magento Error: Mage registry key "_singleton/belvgcolorswatch/observer" already exists

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 372503356274

i went to magento/var/log/ and came up with this log:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:71:
"Mage registry key "_singleton/belvgcolorswatch/observer" already exists"
;i:1;s:3149:"
#0 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/belv...', false)
#2 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(21799): Mage::getSingleton('belvgcolorswatc...')
#3 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#4 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(2600): Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#5 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(2331): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(2275): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('head', true)
#7 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/app/design/frontend/simonshop/default/template/page/1column.phtml(35): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('head')
#8 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(3408): include('/home3/andrewmp...')
#9 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(3439): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/simons...')
#10 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(3453): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#11 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(2613): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(28307): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(14070): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#14 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(11421): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#15 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(11336): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'simon_home_page')
#16 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'simon_home_page')
#17 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(14098): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#18 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(18511): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#19 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/Mdl_UnderConstruction_Controller_Router_Standard.php(72): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(18045): Mdl_UnderConstruction_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/includes/src/__default.php(20837): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /home3/andrewmp/public_html/joobeebb.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}
";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

what could be the problem???

Answer (score 0):

The record number is just a random number that won't help you, however look at the first line of the message, it is quite clear:

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/belvgcolorswatch/observer" already exists
```

So first you can try to disable the module `belvgcolorswatch` to make sure it come from that.

Then investigate the observer and the config files of the module.

You can also try to search for occurence of `Mage::registry` or `Mage::register`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have Magento compilation **enabled**.
You can try after disabling it from back-end.

[image]